# XML - PL/SQL Como obtener los subnodos de los nodos

Tags: xml, plsql, parser

Estoy intentando generar un insert dinamico tomando un archivo XML pero no logro extraer los atributos de mercaderia para otra cadena. Hasta ahora pude extraer los primeros 4

Tiene que seguir esta estructura 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La declaracion es la siguiente: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
--Parseo el contenido del documento xml
v_parse := xmlparser.newparser();
xmlparser.parseclob(v_parse, v_xml);

--Obtenemos el documento xml cargado en un objeto DOM
v_doc := xmlparser.getdocument(v_parse);
xmlparser.freeparser(v_parse);
v_nodos := xmldom.getChildrenByTagName(xmldom.getDocumentelement(v_doc), '*');

--Recorremos cada nodo del arreglo, el arreglo inicio en el item 0  --- Aca devuelve 7
FOR j IN 1 ..  xmldom.getlength(v_nodos) loop

    v_nodo := xmldom.item(v_nodos,j-1);
    -- obtenemos la lista d eelementos que tiene el nodo actual
    v_nodos_hijo := xmldom.getchildnodes(v_nodo);

    --recorremos los  atributos del nodo, obtenemos la lista de atributos que tiene el nodo
    v_atributos := xmldom.getattributes(v_nodo);

    --recorremos cada atributo del nodo
    vv_linea := 'INSERT INTO Fundamento (CODIGO, DESCRIPCION, FEC_INI, FEC_FIN, COD_MONEDA) VALUES (' ;

    FOR k IN 1 .. xmldom.getlength(v_nodos_hijo) LOOP
        --obtenemos un elemento
        v_elemento := xmldom.item(v_nodos_hijo, k-1);   

        IF k = 1 THEN 
            vv_linea :=  vv_linea ||CHR(39)||xmldom.getnodevalue(xmldom.getfirstchild(v_elemento))||CHR(39)||',' ;
        ELSIF k = 2 THEN 
            vv_linea :=  vv_linea ||CHR(39)||xmldom.getnodevalue(xmldom.getfirstchild(v_elemento))||CHR(39)||',' ;
        ELSIF k = 3 THEN 
            vv_linea :=  vv_linea ||'TO_DATE('||CHR(39)||xmldom.getnodevalue(xmldom.getfirstchild(v_elemento))||CHR(39)||','||CHR(39)||'dd/MM/yyyy'||CHR(39)||'),' ;
        ELSIF k = 4 THEN 
            vv_linea :=  vv_linea ||'TO_DATE('||CHR(39)||xmldom.getnodevalue(xmldom.getfirstchild(v_elemento))||CHR(39)||','||CHR(39)||'dd/MM/yyyy'||CHR(39)||'))';
        END IF;

        vv_linea := REPLACE (vv_linea, 'TO_DATE('||CHR(39)||'-'||CHR(39)||','||CHR(39)||'dd/MM/yyyy'||CHR(39)||')' , 'NULL');

    END LOOP;

    dbms_output.put_line(vv_linea);

END LOOP;
```

END;

Alguien podria ayudarme a saber que metodos deberia usar para extraer la seccion de mercaderia?

Gracias!

Comment: Recuerda votar por la respuesta que mas te ayudo.

Comment: pude votar pero como soy usuario nuevo, hasta no tener una minima reputacion de 15 puntos no se imputan. Gracias :D

Comment: Mi móvil llora un poco cada vez que comparten código como imagen. Y mis ojos lloran con él. Por favor, TODO lo que compartas de código, ponlo como texto :)

Answer (score 0):

Un clob no te sirve para almacenar un XML y usar funciones de XML en oracle. Un tipo de dato `xmlType` es mejor. Ejemplo crea una tabla como esta:

`CREATE TABLE Person ( id int primary key, nombre varchar2(20) not null, direccion xmlType);`

Luego le insertas un XML así:

`INSERT INTO Person(id,nombre,direccion) VALUES(1,'Peter Smith',XMLTYPE(
'<MailAddressTo id="1"> <Person>Peter Smith</Person> <Street>10 Downing Street</Street> <Street>20 Principal Avenue</Street> <Street>30 Diagonal Street</Street> <Street>40 Satelite Street</Street> <Street>50 Politecnical Street</Street> <City>London</City> <State>England</State> <Zipcode>22334</Zipcode> </MailAddressTo>'
));`

Una vez hecho esto ya puedes hacer querys usando XPATH como este:

`SELECT extract(DIRECCION, '/MailAddressTo/Street[1]'),--expresion XPATH accede al 1er tag de la lista 
extractvalue(DIRECCION, '/MailAddressTo/Street[4]')--expresion XPATH accede al 4to tag de la lista 
into ValorTag, svalor FROM person;`

O estos updates:

`UPDATE person SET DIRECCION = deleteXML(direccion,'/MailAddressTo/City');--borrando el tag city del xml`

`UPDATE person SET DIRECCION = deleteXML(direccion,'/MailAddressTo/Street[4]');--borrando el 4to tag street de la lista con XPATH;`

O como este ejemplo:

`UPDATE person SET direccion = updateXML(direccion, '/MailAddressTo/Person/text()', 'Stephen G. King',--actualiza el tag person con un nuevo nombre 
'/MailAddressTo/@id', '2');--actualiza la propiedad id del tag MailAddressTo a 2`

También puedes preguntar si existe un nodo:

`Select * from person where existsNode(direccion,'/MailAddressTo[Person="Stephen G. King"]') = 1;`

Espero te sirvan estos ejemplos.

Comment: Estas seguro? lo he usado para procesar archivos anteriormente y nunca he tenido problema. Pero veo de implementar lo que me comentas! Gracias!!

Comment: Con estas funciones es mas sencillo porque puedes usar tecnologías ya probadas de XSL como son XPATH y XQUERY. No digo que lo que hiciste no funcione, si no que lo que te propongo lo vuelve mas sencillo.

Comment: Recuerda votar por la respuesta que mas te ayudo.